# Find the volume of a convex body by inequalities

Tags: inequality, algorithms, convex-analysis

I've seen similar questions on this forum with the condition that all inequalities were bounded by 0 and 1 but this doesn't help me much. I have a convex body in $[0,1]^d$ and $n$ inequalities in the form $a_1 \cdot x_1 + ... + a_d \cdot x_d \leq b$ but my $a$'s and $b$'s can vary between $-100$ to $+100$ and $-2500$ to $+2500$, respectively.

A simple example ($d=2$, $n=4$):

$0\cdot x_1 + 1\cdot x_2 \leq 1$

$0\cdot x_1 - 1\cdot x_2 \leq 0$

$1\cdot x_1 + 1\cdot x_2 \leq 1$

$-1\cdot x_1 + 1\cdot x_2 \leq 0$

A harder example ($d=16$, $n=3$):

$a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_9, a_{10}, a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13}, a_{14}, a_{15}, a_{16}, b$

$-32, -5, 62, -19, -13, 90, -83, 88, 61, -8, 44, -55, 14, -40, 57, -87, 144$

$-82, -43, -2, 33, 9, 28, 91, -10, -32, 76, -29, -61, 35, -34, 76, -24, 13$

$-34, 49, -69, 87, -76, -41, 58, -4, 55, -61, -44, -14, 67, -63, 52, -13, -20$

How would I calculate the volume in such an example?

Comment: Hello ETH fellow student. I'm sorry, i can't help you either, really hard exercise this week :(

Comment: Problemstellung
Gegeben sei ein konvexer Körper K ⊆ R
n
, wobei n typischerweise groß ist. Eine direkte
Berechnung des Volumens ist auf Grund der hohen Dimension praktisch nicht möglich, wir
wählen daher ein Monte-Carlo-Verfahren.
Hierbei müssen wir das Problem im zwei Schritte unterteilen:
• Simuliere gleichverteilte Punkte auf K;
• Schätze das Volumen Voln K von K ab.
Hierbei ist vor allem die Simulation interessant, die Volumenabschätzung ergibt sich als
Grenzwert der Summation genügend vieler Punkte und kann daher auf das erste Problem
zurückgeführt werden. - Hope that helps

Comment: Okay, i got the answer. As more dimensions you have, as more target-shooting you have to do. Simply create a random point in the n-dimensional-room. Then check with the inequalities, if the point is inside the body or not; count that. After you performed x times the target-shooting, you simply can appromixate the volume of the body, by dividing (points inside the body) / (all generated points). If this estimation is v*(1 +/- 0.001) == estimation, you print "yes".